# trigger for inserting data into a table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, triggers, insert-update

Hi guys i AM trying to do a trigger statement (i havnt done any before) so i am basically looking to insert values into a table and m using the following code but its not working any help will be do me good thanks in advance: code m using is following:

```
CREATE TRIGGER updatemovie
           ON movies
           FOR INSERT
           AS
           BEGIN
           INSERT INTO movies values (
            movieID, movieName, movieTime,   movieDate, movieTime,   movieType, Duration, ratings)

           END
```

table i am looking to update is:

```
CREATE TABLE movies( 
movieID int IDENTITY (1,1)NOT NULL,  
movieName varchar (50),
movieTime Time,
movieDate Date, 
movieType varchar (20),
duration varchar (10),
rating varchar (10),
PRIMARY KEY (perID),   
);
```

Answer (score 0):

A trigger will allow you to either cancel the update/insert/delete depending on a condition or it will allow you to keep a record of the update/insert/delete. So if you have a second table (audit ) you can do the following:

update/insert/delete

```
CREATE TRIGGER updatemovie
           ON movies
           FOR INSERT
           AS
           BEGIN
           INSERT INTO movies_audit values (
            inserted.movieID, inserted.movieName,  inserted.movieTime,    inserted.movieDate,  inserted.movieTime,    inserted.movieType,  inserted.Duration,  inserted.ratings)
       END
```

The inserted table is created automatically and contains (for the duration of the trigger) the rows that were just inserted.

Comment: Thanks Benjamin but I haven't got any other table! Didn't understand properly so How thr movies table will get updated? As the insert statement includes movies_audit table?

Comment: Why are using a trigger? Do you just want to enter data into the movies table?

Comment: It's just a requirement to use a trigger to update / insert a table but I have no clue how trigger operate and I been trying for the past day or 2

Comment: You need to check what triggers are and how they work.   You sure the requirement is not something like its a requirement to use a trigger when you update / insert

Comment: I do understand what they are and how they work but i don't get the involvement of other table with movies! Eg if I wana update a movie already in the Movies table then I wana use a trigger rather than writing a query to update it! If that make sense?

Comment: If you want to update a table via a trigger it means that something sets off the trigger (an update/insert/delete on another table) and that in turn kicks off the trigger that updates movies. You don't invoke a trigger like a stored procedure.

Comment: Thanks Benjamin okay so that means if I do an update on movies table it will kick off the trigger and if that's the case how exactly I go about to do that? Like write theinsert statement first?

Comment: A trigger happens as a result of something else happening. What do you want to happen first and then second? What table(s) are going to be updated/inserted

Comment: A trigger happens as a result of something else happening. What do you want to happen first and then second? What table(s) are going to be updated/inserted

Comment: So for instance I want to update a movie in the movie table and update the to movie timings! Only movies table

Comment: When you update two columns in a table the row is locked for the update. So if you update two columns of one table  it will be treated as one operation.

Comment: So that means the solution yiu provided earlier will work? If not than how shall I write it?